# HTML Table Tags Pushed Below Data - Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, html-table, each, enumerable

I thought this would be a simple task: putting `<table></table>` tags around an enumerating `each` method where it goes through the data. Here's the code:

```
<div id="results-panel">
    <table>
        <% @artwork_q.each_with_index do |art, index| %>
            <div class="a-result" id="<%= index %>">
                <%= art.artist.fullname %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </table>
</div>
```

The *problem* is that both the opening and closing `<table></table>` tags end up after all the data has been listed, not surrounding the data as I obviously thought it would:

[image: Chrome Developer Tools Showing Code]

I did try this with the proper `<tr>` and `<td>` tags and it still happened then. This version is for the sake of simplicity and finding the real problem. Any help is incredibly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table is missing `TR` and `TD` tags... that is why the browsers render the table tag outside your div's.

The following should fix it:

```
<div id="results-panel">
    <table>
        <tbody>
        <% @artwork_q.each_with_index do |art, index| %>
            <tr><td>
            <div class="a-result" id="<%= index %>">
                <%= art.artist.fullname %>
            </div>
            </td></tr> 
        <% end %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. So yes that worked but my problem is that I want to surround the `<tr>` in a conditional ruby statement, so that a row is only created every 4th time or so. Even when I put the `<tr>` in a ruby statement: `<%= "<tr>" %>`, (let alone a conditional) it shoves the table tags to the bottom.

Comment: you could use the ruby `%` (modulo) operator in a condition like `<%= "<tr>" if index % 4 == 0 %>` (remember to close it) `<%= "</tr>" if index % 4 == 0 %>`

Comment: Yes I was using that, and you're right. I also think my problem was, I was not including `<td>` elements because I was just "testing", even though I needed them to work. Thank you for the help.